# Embedded functions not using output of previous function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to run 3 functions wrapped into one. See below code, function 1 and 2 are working fine, and if I print `rsmatrix` and `lsmatrix` in function 2 the tables are being output as expected, however in my third function it is returning `lnrn` as NA, even though the third function should have updated it, any ideas why?

```
 lsrn<-NA
```

#Function set 1

```
   nearfunction<-function(x){
      if(x<30){near=((-1*x)/30)+1}
      if(x>29){near=0}
      near}
    
    okfunction<-function(x){
      if(x<7){ok=0}
      if(x>6&x<31){ok=(x/20)-(1/2)}
      if(x<51&x>30){ok=((-1*x)/20)+(5/2)}
      ok}
    
    farfunction<-function(x){
      if(x<21){far=0}
      if(x>20&x<51){far=(x/30)-(2/3)}
      far}
```

#Function 2

```
inputfunction<-function(ls,rs){
  lsmatrix[1,1]<-nearfunction(ls)
  lsmatrix[2,1]<-okfunction(ls)
  lsmatrix[3,1]<-farfunction(ls)
  rsmatrix[1,1]<-nearfunction(rs)
  rsmatrix[2,1]<-okfunction(rs)
  rsmatrix[3,1]<-farfunction(rs)
}
```

#Function 3

```
rulesetfunction<-function(ls,rs){
  inputfunction(ls,rs)
  lnrn<-rsmatrix[1,1]
  return(lnrn)
}

rulesetfunction(10,10)
```

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is bad practice to rely on the presence of external variables when writing functions in R. Your second function requires variables called `ls_matrix` and `rs_matrix` to be present in the calling environment when you run the function, and for them to have specific dimensions. This is a bad idea. What if you want to change these variables' names, or run the function on multiple variables, or you forget to pre-define the variables next time you run your code, or someone else wants to use your code, etc, etc?

Furthermore, your second function `inputfunction` doesn't actually *do* anything. If you write to an existing variable such as `rs_matrix` *inside* a function, it does not change the `rs_matrix` variable *outside* of the function. Instead, the function creates a copy of `rs_matrix` to use internally and writes to that. It would be very difficult to use R if this were not the case. Suppose I had a variable called `x` in my workspace, then I ran some function from a package that happened to use a variable called `x` internally for an intermediate calculation. Without warning, my own `x` variable would be overwritten and lost. Since the function is not writing to the external variables and doesn't return anything, it literally does nothing except consume cpu cycles.

R is a functional language, and users don't expect functions to have side effects. Whilst it *is* possible to write to variables in the calling frame as a side-effect, doing so is almost never necessary, and often just represents poor design.

The first three functions are fine because they take a specific input and give a specific output without reference to external variables, but if they will only ever be used together to create a column vector, why not roll them into a single function:

```r
input_function <- function(x) {
  matrix(c(if(x < 30) 1 - x/30 else 0,
           if(x < 7) 0 else if(x > 30) 5/2 - x/20 else (x - 10)/20,
           if(x < 21) 0 else (x - 20)/30), ncol = 1)
}
```

Then your ruleset function could be as simple as:

```r
ruleset_function <- function(ls, rs) {
  list(ls_matrix = input_function(ls), rs_matrix = input_function(rs))
}
```

Allowing

```r
ruleset_function(10, 15)
#> $ls_matrix
#>           [,1]
#> [1,] 0.6666667
#> [2,] 0.0000000
#> [3,] 0.0000000
#> 
#> $rs_matrix
#>      [,1]
#> [1,] 0.50
#> [2,] 0.25
#> [3,] 0.00
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help!!